# Evaluate $\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{4}}\tan xdx $ using idea of Riemann Sum

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, definite-integrals

Evaluate $$\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{4}}\tan x\,dx$$ using Riemann Sum.

My Attempt:
$$\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{4}}\tan x\, dx=\frac{\pi}{4}\int_{0}^1\tan\left(\frac{\pi}{4}x\right)dx=\frac{\pi}{4}\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{r=1}^{n}\tan\left(\frac{{\pi}r}{4n}\right)$$

After this I am not able to proceed

Comment: Those Riemann sums have no closed formula that might help.

Comment: Maybe do a change of variable first to convert it to the form 1/x. Then make use of https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1322182.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Choose an $N\gg1$ and dividing points 
$$x_k:=\arccos\bigl(2^{-k/(2N)}\bigr)\qquad(0\leq k\leq N)\ .$$
We then have
$$0=x_0<x_1<\ldots<x_N={\pi\over4}\ ,$$
and
$$\cos x_k=2^{-k/(2N)}\qquad(0\leq k\leq N)\ .$$
The mean value theorem gives
$$\cos x_{k-1}-\cos x_k=\sin\xi_k\>(x_k-x_{k-1}),\qquad\xi_k\in[x_{k-1},x_k]\ .$$
It follows that
$$\tan\xi_k\>(x_k-x_{k-1})={\sin\xi_k\over\cos\xi_k}\>(x_k-x_{k-1})={\cos x_{k-1}-\cos x_k\over\cos\xi_k}\ .\tag{1}$$
The unknown point $\xi_k$ is between $x_{k-1}$ and $x_k$. Therefore the value of the  RHS here is between the values one obtains putting $\xi_k:=x_{k-1}$ or $\xi_k:=x_k$. Both lead to the same end result, and the squeeze theorem guarantees that this is also the result for the unknown correct value $\xi_k$. Putting $\xi_k=x_k$ in $(1)$ we obtain
$$\tan\xi_k\>(x_k-x_{k-1})={\cos x_{k-1}\over\cos x_k}-1=2^{1/(2N)}-1\qquad (0\leq k\leq N)\ ,$$
so that admissible Riemann sums $R_N$ become
$$R_N=\sum_{k=1}^N \tan\xi_k\>(x_k-x_{k-1})=N\bigl(2^{1/(2N)}-1\bigr)\ .$$
Now
$$\lim_{N\to\infty}{2^{1/(2N)}-1\over 1/N}=\lim_{t\to0}{\bigl(\sqrt{2}\bigr)^t-1\over t}=\log\sqrt{2}\ ,$$
as is easily checked using Hopital's rule.

Comment: Really nice job! (+1) I'm a fan of the creative choice of $x_k$

Comment: Note that this is part of a general trick, if you happen to know the solution to an integral in advance. Suppose that you know that $\int f(x) dx = F(x)$ and that you can invert the function $F$. Then, to compute $\int_a^b f(x) dx$ by Riemann sums, choose division points at $F^{-1} \left( \tfrac{k}{N} F(a) + \tfrac{N-k}{n} F(b) \right)$. In this case, $F(x) = - \log \cos x$, so $F^{-1}(t) = \cos^{-1}(e^{-y})$. This explains where the formula $\cos^{-1} 2^{-k/(2N)}$ comes from.

Comment: This trick is of course useless for computing new integrals, but useful for problems where the teacher says "using Riemann sums". Similar tricks: If the teacher says "using a $u$-substition", make the substitution $u=F(x)$; if the teacher says "using integration by parts", compute $\int u dv$ where $v=F(x)$ and $u=1$. (Can you tell that I don't like being told how to do something?)

Comment: @Christian Blatter. In (1) why have you chosen to write $\tan \xi_{k}$ instead of $\tan x_{k}$ or $\tan x_{k-1}$. And after that I you have replaced$\xi_{k}$ by $x_{k}$. This is the only confusion that I have

Comment: @Maverick: General Riemann sums are of the form $\sum_{k=1}^N f(\xi_k)\>(x_k-x_{k-1})$ with $\xi_k\in[x_{k-1},x_k]$. When $f$ (as $f:=\tan$) is integrable you can take the lim of arbitrary such sums given that $\lim_{N\to\infty}\bigl(\max_k(x_k-x_{k-1})\bigr)=0$.

Answer (score 3):

Use the fact, that if $a_n \to a$ then $\frac{1}{n} \sum_{r=1}^n a_r \to a.$

Comment: Please elaborate on this